# @HostListener('tap') in Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-directive, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there any way we can listen to @HostListener('tap') or any gesture in NativeScript Angular Application?

I am trying to develop a Directive, scenario for which is when user open a custom modal/component and tap anywhere outside component will close the the modal/component.

Comment: Of course there is. You can have many approaches to solving this problem. If you need more help, however you will need to show your approach. Questions of this sort otherwise where you ask someone else to solve your problem are not optimal. Have a look at this article. => https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0

Comment: @IvanMihaylov, this require using an external HammerJs library to use, while I am looking for resource to check if it is possible with exiting gestures in NativeScript. Not asking anyone to solve my approach; just looking for resource where I can check/read how it is done in Nativescript cuz the official doc doesn't talk about it

Comment: This was an example of how to create the directive with a hostlistner that listens to  a particular event .... Nativescript documentation about how to get an event you are interested in is quite clear from my point of view => https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events

Comment: Are you using a custom modal or the built-in modal dialog?

Comment: @manoj, i am using custom modal

Comment: Then yes you may able to use HostListener. What's the issue you are facing, do you have Playground sample?

Answer (score 1):

```
@HostListener('tap', ['$event']) onTap(event: TapGestureEventData) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

In my case, I was wondering how to pass gesture event data to the handler. Found the answer [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1747).

Comment: Do you know how can we get the target tapped element not the element the event is attached if you know what mean?